# Search throughout an chm file

Tags: file-search, mobi

I need to know the "pages" of an chm file which contain a certain word, as one regularly does in pdfs or word docs using a regular search.
The chm file does not allow me to do this.

How should I proceed? 
I am on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chm files can de [decompiled](https://docs.microsoft.com/previous-versions/windows/desktop/htmlhelp/decompiling-a-help-file) using hh.exe.  For example, given the file:

> C:\test\test.chm

You could run:

> hh.exe -decompile test C:\test\test.chm

This will unpack the HTML files to C:\test.  These files could then be searched through using a command-line tool for example:

> findstr /s /i /n "poolmon" *.htm

Comment: I have no idea about code. Could you offer a step by step guidelines?

Comment: Create a working directory, e.g. `C:\test` and copy the CHM file to it. From there, you can launch a command prompt (cmd.exe) and change directory to it by running: `CD \test`. Once inside the directory, you can unpack the chm file by running `hh.exe -decompile test C:\test\test.chm` Where test.chm is the file you have. To then search the files unpacked, you could run: `findstr /s /i /n "tosearch" *.htm` This should print the "files" containing the term. If needed You can actually then view just the page in IE by running from Start - Run:: `mk:@MSITStore:C:\test\test.chm::/path/file.htm`

Comment: How do I create a "working directory"?

Comment: create a folder called `C:\test`, does that help?

Comment: In bold is the file name and after the colon is the line number.  You should be able to just select the text with the mouse. If you want just a list of file names you could use the `M` switch, e.g. `findstr /s /i /M "tosearch" *.htm`  To print them to a file: `findstr /s /i /M "poolmon" *.htm > files.txt`  The new file `files.txt` will then have a list of files that have the search term in if that's helpful.

Comment: I don't understand what you're after as a workflow. The `hh.exe` command will decompile the chm file back to the individual files, these can then be search for whatever you need to find. The example command line tool `findstr` is useful to search in files (*.htm), so `findstr /s /i /M "tosearch" *.htm > files.txt` will create a file called files.txt that contains a list of all files the text `tosearch` is within. If you prefer to use an interface, as the files are unpacked, you might be able to search the contents with Explorer or use a tool such as Agent Ransack, that has a free version.

Comment: Sorry for all the hesitation. Unfortunately the search of the keyword doesn't always work, even using Windows search box of the folder. For example the word "usage" in the following page (downloadable from https://filebin.net/eu7t2afoj1ke90dq) when in the "TEST" FOLDER. iIS there a limit for the finds? There now 168450 html files . What is index.hkk for? thanks for your patience

Comment: `findstr /s /i /N "usage" *.htm` finds line 20 and 24 as having the word usage but is you want a user interface to search with, maybe try using Agent Ransack if Windows search isn't helping.  Agent Ransack by https://www.mythicsoft.com/ is a good file searching tool and there is a free version.

Comment: How can I rename every htm file by the string of characters in its headline? For example this one https://filebin.net/o5qc0c8aikljzh6a would be named  "motor voter law"

Comment: The issue might be the title contains characters that can't be used in the file name.  Also, given that example, I can't be 100% sure if the title is always in the same HTML markup.  The following one-line Powershell command will print the file name and then the "heading" - https://pastebin.com/vEPxrfsJ You will need to run this one-liner from the same directory as the htm files.

Comment: in the chm file those "headings" are the ones in the "index"; in the conversion into htm an index.hkk file was created

Answer (score 1):

7-Zip can open HTML Help files (`.chm`) and unpack them, revealing the raw HTML contents (and search/keyword indices, should they exist):

[image]

This way, you can use your favorite recursive content search (`grep -r`, Notepad++) to search all HTML files. Unfortunately, you’ll have to make an educated guess as to the “human readable” name of the pages you find.

I’m not sure what you mean by “mobi file”. `.mobi` is an eBook format. It is not related to HTML Help files (`.chm`) in any way.

Comment: I tried but the file ends up corrupted